# How to sample from a mixture of densities of transformed random variables?

Tags: sampling, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Suppose we are given a set of $m$ random variables, $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_m$, defined over the same set $\mathcal{X}$, with known densities $p_{X_i}$, for $i=1$, $2$, ..., $m$. Assume that getting independent samples from each $p_{X_i}$ is cheap.

We are also given a (deterministic) function $f: \mathcal{X} \mapsto \mathcal{Z}$, and we use it to define the random variables $Z_i = f(X_i)$, for $i=1$, $2$, ..., $m$. Let $p_{Z_i}$ denote the resulting density of the random variable $Z_i$. Assume that $f$ is a "complicated" function (e.g., non-invertible) and therefore the densities $p_{Z_i}$ are intractable to compute analytically.

Now, for a given $m$-dimensional $\alpha$, we define the mixture density $p_{Z^\alpha} = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i p_{Z_i}$ and we want to get $n$ samples from this mixture distribution.

For this purpose, is it a valid procedure to get samples $x_1$, ..., $x_n$ from the mixture density $p_{X^\alpha} = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i p_{X_i}$ (which is easy and cheap) and then obtain the corresponding  $z_1$, ..., $z_n$ by computing $z_j = f(x_j)$?

I have a strong feeling that this is valid, providing me with samples from $p_{Z^\alpha}$, as desired, but I am not being able to prove it...

Comment: Yes--and this doesn't require the variables even to have densities.  You might find that drawing a probability tree to describe the situation might be convincing.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it our afterward. Basically, I just need to sample from $p_{Z_i}$ with probability $\alpha_i$. Getting a sample $z$ from $p_{Z_i}$ is obviously equivalent to sampling $x$ from $p_{X_i}$ and then computing $z=f(x)$.